# Read a directory listing into Powershell, then display every other filename to the screen

Tags: powershell

Here is the Powershell script that I have created so far:

```
dir C:\Windows\System32 | Sort-Object -Descending
```

My end goal is to list all the files (files only - no sub directories) in the following directory, sorted by filename in descending order. Next I need to read this directory listing created into Powershell, then display every other filename to the screen.

I was trying to find a way to do this by piping the sorted results into the Foreach-Object cmdlet, and then reading "Object" from the resulting list, using the Get-Content cmdlet, and the FullName proprety of each object - like: Get-Content $_.FullName

```
dir C:\Windows\System32 | Sort-Object -Descending | ForEach-Object
```

Any ideas how to make this happen with those cmdlets?

Comment: `ForEach-Object` has an optional begin scriptblock you can use to initialize a counter, so append `|ForEach-Object {$i=0}{$i++;if($i%2){$_}}` to output all even entries.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: You don't even need a separatee increment command, the position of the `++` dertermines if it is pre or post the modulus. `|ForEach-Object {$i=0}{if(++$i%2){$_}}` or `|ForEach-Object {$i=0}{if($i++%2){$_}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get the index number of an item in an array with `.IndexOf()`. you can get the even numbers of a list of numbers by using "mod 2 = zero". something like this ...

```
$TargetDir = "$env:windir\system32"

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $TargetDir -File |
    Sort-Object -Property Name

foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)
    {
    # if "number mod 2 = zero", then it's an even number
    if ($FileList.IndexOf($FL_Item) % 2 -eq 0)
        {
        $FL_Item.Name
        }
    }
```